# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for feed

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

i make code but i have problem the display information json , my json Facebook feed page , and have error log Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=feed&access_token=CAAHfgIvJhksBANmQMEQe6XMApQ7NyxOOkdlKVyb8UIHJXrmVKubeMTZCTs2kkqz3bJ8DGvu6Xky1wrOwdhzigfOdbna3ahL3929MntYwzbvEHr8Ew86wcbZAb4gOnRYKa7uYQpuAihhkZAAeVARMG7N0FGxiqZBX0Ka9ZAzR3HiZCqAjbH13k6ZCXE8EgPl7EQZCILerc3xI2wZDZD",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (parsed_json) {
            var feed parsed_json['feed'];
            var feed = {};
            feed['أضاءة القمر '] = feed['message'] + '%',
            for (index in feed) {
                if (feed.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                    var newHourlyString = index + ': ' + feed[index];
                    var newHourlyParagraph = $('<p/style="margin-right:6px;margin-bottom:10px; position: initial;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 800;">').text(newHourlyString);
                    $(".astro").append(newHourlyParagraph);
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you format your code?

Comment: ok, now you can se your syntax error: `var feed parsed_json['feed'];`. Missing `=`.

Comment: Also, `feed["ARABIC TEXT"] = feed["message"]+"%"` needs to end in a `;` not a `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var feed parsed_json['feed'];
```

With:

```
var feed = parsed_json['feed'];
```

You are missing the `=` sign after `var feed`

## A little deeper insight.

The following lines:

```
var feed parsed_json['feed'];
var feed = {};
feed['أضاءة القمر '] = feed['message'] + '%',
```

Have some typos and seem a little bit odd, for instance, there is a missing equal sign: `var feed parsed_json['feed'];` should be `var feed = parsed_json['feed'];`

Another typo is in the third line of the ones i've pointed, you are ending a line with a comma instead of a semicolon. This: `feed['أضاءة القمر '] = feed['message'] + '%',` should be: `feed['أضاءة القمر '] = feed['message'] + '%';`

And last, but not least, you are defining a `var feed` and then redeclaring it, meaning that `feed['message']` in your code will most likely be `undefined`. My suggestion:

```
var feedParsed = parsed_json['feed'];
var feed = {};
feed['أضاءة القمر '] = feedParsed['message'] + '%';
```

Comment: stil have error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

Comment: his work thank you , but he display undefined message from json .